# C++ function naming convention

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

In one of my colleagues code review for c++, one of my team mates asked her to put an underscore for the beginning of the function since it was not exposed via the header file.

But I found it not compulsory(left to the programmer's style) for the following reasons:

1. This was an old code base and none of the code followed this coding convention.
2. This was a function name and not a method defined in the class.
3. Most of my company uses Java and is much familiar with Java more than c++. Putting an underscore would create more confusion than clarity.

I think this question is quite subjective. Am I wrong here? Should we put an underscore for each function not exposed via header file?

Comment: If the function is declared at global scope that's not even legal (if you are talking about a function name beginning with an underscore).

Comment: Don't do that. [Identifiers beginning with an underscore in global namespace is reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/3309790).

Comment: For me I prefer not to, because it make variable and function names become similar to predefined built-in variables or functions.

Comment: _@var_ Putting an underscore at the end of a symbol keeps the doctor away.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Keeps the... Who? :) (lucky with your nick, otherwise no rhymes are to be found in that aphorism to make it memorable ;) )

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I'm simply extrapolating. That leaves the dimension of rhyming rules :3

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Its underscore at the beginning of the function name declared in the global namespace.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, the function is defined in the global namespace, but, putting an underscore did not give any compilation errors/warnings? I am using a very old version of c++.

Comment: @var Simply don't use underscore at the beginning of symbol names, these are reserved for compiler implementation specific stuff. It's a convention mentioned in the c++ standard, so there won't be any warnings or errors about it. Similar as with undefined behavior.